# Ruby application doesn't load Bootstrap classes

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing the views for a Ruby application.This is an example:

http://mailclient-dmuldoon.c9.io/app/statistics/page_2

The first table has the "table table-hover" class, but it doesn't work, bootstrap doesn't load correctly.

I don't know anything about Ruby, how can i fix it? what should i check?

Bootstrap is called in this file: app/assets/javascriptsapplication.js

With this line of code:

//= require components/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: The page you linked to is password protected...

Comment: are you loading the bootstrap css files?

Comment: bootstrap gems installed in your application? Check your Gemfile

Comment: The e-mail is: felipepinoredes@gmail.com
The password: Felipe2016

Comment: Where can i look if it's loading the bootstrap css files? what file do i check?

How can i check the bootstrap gems?

Comment: @FelipePino the bootstrap css is loaded, use chrome's developer tool you can see the content of the merged version of application.css, and on line around 3483, there is comment saying the bootstrap is loaded.

Comment: Imho you are using different/conflicting css frameworks. If on your page you only want to use bootstrap, I would create a different css file for that. So copy `application.css` to `dashboard.css` (or something similar) and only include the pieces of css you need.

Comment: I went to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss, deleted all the lines and only let @import "bootstrap"; but the problem persists (and also let some styles, but that was expected because i deleted the lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you also have Bootstrap CSS files loaded? Depending on the Bootstrap gem you have loaded, this might also be required. In app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss you might need to have the following three lines:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'bootstrap/theme';
```

Comment: The line @import "bootstrap"; was already there, when i added the lines of bootstrap-sprockets and bootstrap/theme i got an error that told me that those files weren't found.

How do i install them? do i actually need them?

Comment: There's a file called `Gemfile` in the project root directory. The gem I typically include in projects where I'm using Bootstrap is called [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass). The author has reasonably good documentation for it on the GitHub page.

Comment: The files were not well imported, thanks to your reply i was able to do it well.